# Проиграть видео при наведении на маркер Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, ar

Создал AR приложении по видео туториалу на Unity для android, суть которой в том, что при наведении камеры телефона маркер в приложении должен начаться проигрыш заранее загруженного видео. Проблема в том, что при запуске приложения автоматически начинается проигрыш видео, а не при наведении на маркер.

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит показать код, которым ты пытаешься вызвать проигрывание видео, по наведение на маркер?

Вообще, стоило бы иметь какое-то событие при наведении на этот маркер в классе камеры, которой ты смотришь.. А может оно уже есть во фреймфорке, который ты используешь.. Не понятно без контекста.

что-то типа такого:

```
public class ARCamera : Monobehaviour // не обязательно monobehaviour
{
    public static event Action MarkerHoverOver = delegate {}

    private void Update()
    {
         //твоя логика поиска маркера, если видишь маркер, вызываешь событие
         OnMarkerHover.Invoke();
    }
}

public class VideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour // не обязательно 
{
    private void Awake()
    {
         ARCamera.MarkerHoverOver += OnMarkerHoverOver(); //  подписка на событие
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
         ARCamera.MarkerHoverOver -= OnMarkerHoverOver(); // отписка, чтобы не было утечек памяти из-за того, что event статический
    }

    private void OnMarkerHoverOver()
    {
         //здесь запускаешь свой плеер. Можно конечно и напрямую вызвать, без события.
    }
}
```

В настройках твоего плеера , кстати, может тупо стоять флаг типа 'playOnAwake' или что-то в таком духе

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать Unity и создаю приложение по видеотуториалам. В настройках плеера перепробовал убрать/поставить галочки, нет ожидаемого результата.

Comment: Без кода, не понятно, как именно ты пытаешься это сделать.

Comment: Это мой первый опыт на Unity, значит без кода мою проблему нельзя решить, я правильно понял?

Comment: Как твой player узнает о том, что там что-то на что-то навелось? В идеале твой player вообще не должен быть никак связан с камерой и твоим AR фреймворком. Да даже если и связан, то как твой плеер узнает об этом событии? Можно конечно все в инспекторе накидать , но это опять же делать надо в скриптах...